# Font not set to Arial in outgoing email (by SendGrid) from my .NET windows app

Tags: c#, html, .net, email, html-email

The text in the outgoing emails from my app is plain non-proportional text.

I tried to make it Arial.  But it is still not Arial.

Here is what I send to SendGrid, which sends the email:

```
<p><font face="Arial"><pre>Message</pre></font></p>
```

Comment: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-code-html-email-newsletters

Comment: https://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/design/limitations-of-html-email

Comment: @UweKeim It's not something about mailchimp. It's about HTML.

Comment: The OP has enclosed the Message inside `<pre>`, which imposes `monospace` fonts. I am not sure why you say "You don't say!" Not sure if you are being rude or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is using these two:

- `<font>`
- `<pre>`

Replace it with the following:

```html
<p style="font-family: Arial; white-space: pre-wrap;">Message</p>
```

The `<pre>` changes the font family here. And the `<font>` is deprecated.

The `style` attribute will be a replacement for the following:

- `<font>` => `font-family: Arial;`
- `<pre>` => `white-space: pre-wrap;`

Comment: **More info:** You enclosed the `Message` inside `<pre>`, which imposes `monospace` fonts. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks, Soolie!  It worked.  Plus, my hyperlinks (within 'message') still work too -- that's why I put in the <pre></pre>